# iOS8 IndexedDB Blob Support

Tags: ios8, blob, indexeddb

I can't seem to find anyone else running into this online, but I'm having an issue saving blobs to an IndexedDB in iOS8.

Here's an example: http://robnyman.github.io/html5demos/indexeddb/

This page grabs a picture, saves it to the IndexedDB, and then creates an objectURL to display it, and it works well in Chrome and FireFox.

In Safari on iOS8.0 (and the 8.1 beta), the object refuses to store- in the console when connected to a Mac, I'm getting the following:

> DOM IDBDatabase Exception 25: The data being stored could not be cloned by the internal structured cloning algorithm.

Any ideas? Is this just not implemented? Honestly I can't find any documentation on iOS8's implementation of IndexedDB.

Thanks!

Edit: This is still an issue on iOS9

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Nope. Filed a ticket with on Apple's web reporter about a year ago to no response. You could go with a conversion to an ArrayBuffer or Base64 strings (ugh) but obviously those are less than ideal.

Comment: can it store arraybuffers directly? I'm converting one to base64 now to get it in there but it would be faster and less data to just put a buffer in there

Comment: Come to think of it, I didn't try it out. I know standard Chrome and FireFox (not iOS) can store ArrayBuffers in iDBs no problem, but didn't try it on iOS. I did try base64 strings on iOS, which worked of course as they are just [bloated] strings.